# Removeable board sized ssd

Tags: integrated-circuit, motherboard, ssd

Me and my friends are starting work on a small robotics product.
We are just starting out in product creation, and were wondering how to transfer our programming to the bot's ssd.
We realize we can get the data over wifi, but we'd still require the basic infrastructure to handle the requests.
We thought we'd do a removable ssd that we could simply unplug from the bot's motherboard, and plug into a ssd to usb chip.
Notice we are looking for a small chip, the size you'd find on a stick of ram or smartphone, not a consumer pc sized drive.
My question is, does a removable ssd chip exist, and where might we find one?

Comment: What about an SD card or flash drive?

Comment: You don't say how small you really want it, but I've used microSD successfully and there are USB readers/writers for interfacing with computers. It's a reasonably widely used technology.

Comment: Also you can make a "ghetto" socket for it for using a on breadboard/veroboard by soldering pins to a microSD-to-[regular]SD adapter, e.g.: http://www.protostack.com/blog/2011/09/8-breadboard-hacks/

Answer (score 1):

There's something called NGFF as in next generation form factor, or [M.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) (see link).

Passerby's suggestion is probably the best, especially if you opt for a usb stick since you can hotplug it into the host. With a PCI or SATA drive you need specific hardware, or you need to reboot your machine. If speed is not of great concern a usb2.0 stick will do, you can also opt for 3.0 if you need the additional MBps. I fear SD cards are a bit more unreliable than usb stick, and ofc the ssd option is the most reliable, but also the priciest.

Comment: Both PCI and SATA should support hotplugging if you get the right device.

Comment: Thanks, for the prototype we'll do something like a flash drive or sd card, but do ssd's in mass production.

Comment: I don't know what you base your assertion of SD (relative) unreliability on. I've used microSD in various projects for years with no problems. Given that they are used/usable in a lot of smartphones, cameras, field-grade GPSs etc., I doubt they are any more unreliable than USB in general.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff I've just experienced more failed SDc than usb stick, but it is not much relevant since I am speaking of personal use.